# QTreeWidget expand animation on double click

Tags: python, qt4, python-2.7, pyside, qtreewidget

I have created a `QTreeWidget` and set animation to true (`setAnimated(true)`).
When I'm clicking on a mark (triangle) at the left of item it expands smoothly, but when I'm double clicking on the item it expands too fast (almost like there is no "animated" flag set).
I want smooth animation on double click too. How can I solve this problem?

`QTreeView` calls `QTreeViewPrivate::expandOrCollapseItemAtPos` on mark click and `QTreeViewPrivate::expand` on double click, so I have no access to these methods.

I'm using PySide for creating Qt application (but I've tried C++ and the problem is the same).

Comment: Could you post a manageable version of your code?

Comment: Can you just connect the `itemDoubleClicked` signal to the expand slot?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the click behaviour. Check the event if it's a double click or not and then you can redirect the event to the appropriate call. You should check the state if it's already clicked or not to prevent a second animation which might happen.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is, double click also rise a single click in default implementation.
Before expand animation, the default implementation call `QAbstractItemView::setState(AnimatingState)` to set internal state for animation.

And in `QAbstractItemView::mouseReleaseEvent()`, `QAbstractItemView::setState(NoState)` is called before animation finished. After this, animation terminated immediately.

Use following code to work around:

```
void YourSubTreeView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    QAbstractItemView::State preState = state();
    QTreeView::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    if (preState == QAbstractItemView::AnimatingState)
        setState(preState);
}
```