# QTreeView animation of expand

Tags: qt, animation, expand, qtreeview

Qt 5.7. 
I have QTreeView with setAnimated(true).
If expand by branch icon, expanding is animated.
If expand by double click on element, expanding is not work.
If overload mouseDoubleClickEvent() and try QTreeView::expand() it not work for animation too.

Any idias?

Comment: See this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19441532/4297146, It works fine.

Comment: Yep, it work! Thanks!